# IIS 7.5: Can browse website from LAN but not from outside

Tags: web, iis-7.5, localhost, portforwarding

I have an MVC4 website set up in IIS 7.5. When I browse the website using my computer's IP address from a computer within my network, it works. But the website does not load when accessed from outside of the network.

I have a router and set up port forwarding on port 80 (also tried with others but I'll stick with this for the question), to forward to my PC's IP address. Also allowed incoming TCP requests on port 80 in my firewall.

In IIS 7.5 I am using the default website with the default bindings, which include a binding for port 80, all unassigned IP addresses and no hostname.

Locally I can browse my website using this address:

```
Local PC IP -xxx.xxx.x.xxx/LBSPrototype1
```

Shouldn't I be able to access my website from outside of the network using:

```
Router IP - xxx.xxx.x.x/LBSPrototype1
```

Since I forwarded port 80 to my local PC? Or alternatively if I use a different port:

```
Router IP - xxx.xxx.x.x:PORT/LBSPrototype1
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, any ideas as to what I might have left out?

Answer (score 0):

Tried disabling your firewall ? maybe some firewall rules are blocking you

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't make a difference :/